# Are the pronoun and verb needed in this sentence to prevent ambiguity of the antecedent?

Tags: subordinate-clauses, compound-sentences

We have a sentence like this:

> Transients are individuals just passing through, not contributing to
> the local population and its demographic rates, and they
> are thus very unlikely to be recaptured.

Is it possible to remove **"they are"** behind the comma? So it would sound like this:

> Transients are individuals just passing through, not contributing to
> the local population and its demographic rates, and thus very unlikely to be recaptured.

It would be much more elegant. But the catch also is that the **"thus"** doesn't refer to the most proximate sentence "not contributing to the local ....", but to the one at the beginning - "just passing through". Is that a problem somehow?

Comment: So the transients were physically captured at one point? I don't really understand the context.

Comment: Seems fine. Whether you can delete "they are" has nothing to do with what "thus" refers to; as long as the parallel is with "transients are", the repeated "they are" can be removed. But it sounds like you actually want to know if "thus" is valid?

Comment: Yes, the sentence doesn't make sense. But the sentence << Transients are individuals just passing through, not contributing to the local population and its demographic rates, and thus [they are] ignored in many surveys >> is fine in the deleted form.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs it's about studies with marked animals (e.g. bird ringing). Yes, they were captured once, and if they are transients, they are very unlikely to be recaptured.

Comment: @StuartF thanks! Yes, I would like to know if this use of "thus" is valid, when it is not referring to the most proximate subclause...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth why doesn't it make sense? Because of missing context? Or, is the current use of "thus" not valid, when it refers to the beginning of sentence and not the previous subclause?

Comment: Transients are [individuals just passing through], [not contributing to the local population and its demographic rates], and [thus very unlikely to be recaptured].

Comment: @BillJ It seems  that "thus" should be out of the bracket: it is not part of the subject complement ("Thus, transients are very unlikely to be recaptured;")

Comment: @LPH do you mean to split it into two sentences?  (and you wrote the second one?)

Comment: The first comment spells out the missing context; as it stands, we are wondering just what is happening when transients are placed in captivity. Would-be transients, maybe.

Comment: @Tomas No, I am trying to explain that the bracketing should be as follows:  "Transients are [individuals just passing through], [not contributing to the local population and its demographic rates], and thus [very unlikely to be recaptured].".

Comment: @LPH thanks for the answer. Can you please explain what the bracketing is for?

Comment: It's showing the phrase structure, particularly which phrases are parallels of each other.

Comment: @Tomas The brackets aim at delimiting the scope of the verbal form "are"; however, there are problems with user Billj's determination of limits: "[individuals just passing through]" is a subject complement and so is "[very unlikely to be recaptured]"; however, "[not contributing to the local population and its demographic rates]" is not; "are not contributing to" has to be reckoned with as the continuous present of "contribute"; in the other cases "to be" is the copula, whereas now it is an auxiliary.

Comment: What @StuartF said. The present or absence of ***they are*** doesn't make the slightest difference to the inherent ambiguity as to what ***thus*** refers back to.

Comment: You can remove your comma-restricted nonessential stuff in the middle and see that this is grammatically fine: *Transients are individuals just passing through and thus very unlikely to be recaptured.* If you mean that the reason they unlikely to be recaptured is that they are passing through, then it is semantically correct too.

Comment: If that's a citation, can you provide a link to it? It reads like a construction…

Comment: Yes, it is a problem, and it will immediately be solved simply by dropping the word 'thus'. 

You are quite right to point out the catch that 'thus' refers not to the most proximate 'not contributing…', but to the earlier 'just passing through' and you could remove any problem wither by re-writing the whole sentence, or simply by dropping the word 'thus'.